# How to add a property to an object

Tags: javascript

I need to pass the exact data to the webAPI:

```
{
 email: "useremail",
 password: "userpassword",
 grant_type: "password"
}
```

From the login form, I receive the following data:

```
{
 email: "useremail",
 password: "userpassword"
}
```

I need to add the **grant_type: "password"** to the object.

Here is my method

```
signIn(credentials) {

  console.log(credentials);

  this.authService.login(credentials)

    .subscribe(result => { 
      if (result)
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      else  
        this.invalidLogin = true; 
    });
}
```

The credentials is the data coming from the Login form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have this:

```
let jsonObject = {
  email: "useremail",
  password: "userpassword",
}
```

I think you can simply do like so

```
jsonObject['grant_type'] = password;
```

Otherwise, simple and effective:

```
let extendedJsonObject = {
  email: jsonObject.email,
  password: jsonObject.password,
  grant_type: 'password'
};
```

As **@jonrsharpe** said in the comments, you can also do so:

```
let extendedJsonObject = { grant_type: 'password', ...jsonObject }
```

According to **@Kyrsberg** you can also do

```
let extendedJsonObject = Object.assign({grant_type: 'password'}, jsonObject);
```

Comment: Or `let extendedJsonObject = { grant_type: 'password', ...jsonObject }`, using object destructuring.

Comment: I didn't know you could destructure objects, I thought it was only arrays. Thanks for the heads up, this will be really useful !

Comment: (I allowed myself to edit my post to include your answer)

Comment: I believe you can also do this: `let extendedJsonObject  = Object.assign({grant_type: 'password'}, jsonObject)`

Comment: I'm not able to test it right now but even if I take your word for it, I'd rather use @jonrsharpe way since it's more concise and uses Typescript operators. But I'll do the same and update my answer !

Comment: Spread properties are **not** "TypeScript operators". They are neither "TypeScript" nor "operators". They are just, well, spread properties, which TypeScript happens to support.

Comment: Aren't they part of the Ecma script syntax or something ?

Comment: They are a stage 3 proposal, if I recall correctly. See https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying

Answer (score 0):

What you appear to want to do is to add a property to an object. **This is one of the most basic operations in all of JavaScript**. It is something that you would learn early on in any of the hundreds or thousands of tutorials, intros, beginner books, blog posts, and documentation pages that cover JavaScript.

I strongly suggest you go back and review whatever materials you were using to learn JavaScript. For instance, you could start with [this friendly intro to property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

This has nothing to do with TypeScript or Angular. TypeScript is a type layer on top of JS. Angular is an application framework. Your question is purely about JavaScript. It's a bit concerning that you thought this problem might have something to do with TypeScript or Angular. It would indicate you don't actually understand the relationship among the tools you are using, namely JavaScript and TypeScript and Angular. Understand clearly that you are working with the language called JavaScript. You must study it carefully and know it well before even starting to work with TypeScript or Angular.

You also seem deeply confused about the meaning of the term "JSON". **JSON is exactly one thing: a text-based format for exchanging information**. JavaScript objects are **not** JSON, although they resemble each other (hence the "J" of "JSON"), and can be converted back and forth ("parsing" and "stringifying"). Your problem has absolutely nothing to do with JSON. The objects you are working with, which include properties such as `email`, are **not** JSON. If you insist on calling them JSON--and there is no shortage of similarly misguided folks trying to work in JavaScript--you will merely confuse yourself and those around you. These objects are plain, old, ordinary, JavaScript objects, and that's what you should call them.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I may say I dont have a good knowledge in frontend dev (*.js languages) I am still learning.